# What does 'Be gone' mean in this expression

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

What does `Be gone` mean ?

```
A) I don't like happiness.
B) Be gone then
```

I think it means `Go die`. Am I right?

Comment: No. it means 'go away' or to be blunt - 'get lost!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **go** is, among other meanings, to leave or depart.

Asking someone to **be gone** means that you want them to have left or departed.

In other words, **be gone** (or, as it's also written, **begone**) means "go away."